# Making a paperback book from a LaTeX file

Tags: floats, geometry, books

I was directed here by the good people at [Ask Metafilter](http://ask.metafilter.com/277724/Making-a-paperback-book-from-a-LaTeX-file). This site will only let me post 2 links, so for the others please look there.

I need to reformat a LaTeX document: [PDF](http://www.uoftfacultydivest.com/files/fossil-fuel-divest-new-2015-03-26.pdf) for printing as a paperback.

at the Asquith Press Book Printing Service in Toronto.

1. What's the ideal format for a PDF to be printed as a book in this way? In particular, I mean page size, margins, and any other special considerations.
2. What LaTeX package(s) should I use to accomplish this with this document?
3. Can I use package{geometry} exclusively to set up the right format?
4. We don't have heaps of money to spend on this, so all the figures will be in black and white. Any tips on how to make them look as good as possible would be appreciated.

Bonus: is it at all feasible to get an ISBN number for a project like this?

Thank you!

---

More info:

Thanks for the suggestions so far:

I tried making a 'book' class document using some basic settings:

http://www.sindark.com/350/fossil-fuel-divest-new-book.pdf

The .tex and .bib have the same filename and location.

As you can see, there are a number of problems.

For one, the document necessarily has some rather long chapter/section titles. This is inevitable, since this document needs to respond directly to particular policies and procedures. Is there a command to get rid of the overly-long headers at the top of pages?

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SX! We normally prefer to see one question at a time. Perhaps you could tell us what the publisher specifies, what you have tried, and ask something specific about how to achieve a better result?

Comment: Unless the figures are made in `tikz`, `metapost`, or `picture` mode, that part isn't really a TeX question. Process the figures using other programs,save them as cropped PDFs (preferably) and then include them with `\includegraphics` from the `graphicx` package.

Comment: The ISBN question is not a TeX question.

Comment: several papers on self-publishing have been published in *tugboat*, and they may be helpful.  go to http://tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/listkeyword.html and use you browser's search function to search for "self-publishing".

Comment: See my example design for Mike Brotherton's Star Dragon in Memoir, a xelatex example posted here which does proper trim box information in a .pdf, &c.

Comment: The press should give you the guidelines regarding what fonts and margins they want you to use. Get those and edit the question to ask about implementation. Should be quite simple....

Comment: Please only one question at a time. I'm voting to close as unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question is very wide and may not be suitable for this forum in its present form. Nevertheless, a short try:

> First: what's the ideal format for a PDF to be printed as a book in
>   this way? In particular, I mean page size, margins, and any other
>   special considerations.

You should check with the printing office. Some are limited to standard sizes, but even then offer a wide range (A4, A5, maybe Letter), others let you choose whatever you want and then cut the paper accordingly. It also depends on what you want. I prefer A4, because it reads nicer in my opinion and offers much space for images. A5 is smaller and can thus be easily put into the pocket (if you intend something that people should carry around with them), but is thicker and often does not offer enough space to reproduce complicated graphics in a readable way. Same for the margins. KOMA offers possibilities to calculate margins such that the printed area has a nice length to read, otherwise experiment what is pleasing and easy to read given your chosen format. You will want to have a binding correction, because you loose some margin space in the middle, where the pages meet. This must be adjusted to the thickness of the book and the stiffness of the binding; ask the printing office for advice.

> Second: what LaTeX package(s) should I use to accomplish this with
>   this document?

Nothing special so far and/or too general a question. Come back when you have specific questions on how to achieve something particular.

> Third: can I use package{geometry} exclusively to set up the right
>   format?

It depends. If you are using the standard classes you **should** use `geometry`. If you will be using the KOMA classes you should use their built-in formatting tools instead.

> Fourth: we don't have heaps of money to spend on this, so all the
>   figures will be in black and white. Any tips on how to make them look
>   as good as possible would be appreciated.

Just make sure to use the whole 256-grey-scales spectrum (truncate the unused histogram space) and save them in an appropriate format (png for bitmap, pdf/eps for vector) to not sacrifice image quality (no jpg, unless the image is jpg already; then you cannot save it).

> Bonus: is it at all feasible to get an ISBN number for a project like
>   this?

Have no experience with that.

Comment: `geometry` can savely be used with KOMA-script and is the recommended way if one has to follow specific margin settings.